# PrimeNG Dropdown Button not reacting/working properly

Tags: angular, primeng

So I am following this tutorial on how to implement a prime ng dropdown button: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/dropdown

I followed the tutorial and the designed dropdown button is showing with value "New York". But when I click on it, nothing happens. I would expect it to dropdown and show me the other options, but nothing happens. I installed angular/cdk aswell.

my html:

```
<p-dropdown [options]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCityCode" optionLabel="name" optionValue="code"></p-dropdown>
```

my ts (shortened):

```
interface City {
  name: string,
  code: string
}

cities: City[];

selectedCityCode: string;

constructor() {
  this.cities = [
    {name: 'New York', code: 'NY'},
    {name: 'Rome', code: 'RM'},
    {name: 'London', code: 'LDN'},
    {name: 'Istanbul', code: 'IST'},
    {name: 'Paris', code: 'PRS'}
  ];
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I believe you're not using latest version of PrimeNg (11.x) in your application.

Comment: yeah cause the latest version does not work somehow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puh, this was funny. Apparently I had no import of `BrowserAnimationsModule` in my module.ts. After import, everything worked.